# Bcbio-gff File creation issue

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, gff

When creating a file using GFF.write(), i get a new line with "annotation remark" as a source, followed by ASCII encoding of sequence regions:

```
##gff-version 3
##sequence-region NC_011594.1 1 16779
NC_011594.1 annotation  remark  1   16779   .   .   .   gff-version=3;sequence-region=%28%27NC_011594.1%27%2C 0%2C 16971%29,%28%27NC_042493.1%27%2C 0%2C 132544852%29, (continues on and on)
NC_011594.1 RefSeq  gene    1   1531    .   +   .   Dbxref=GeneID:7055888;ID=gene-COX1;Name=COX1;gbkey=Gene;gene=COX1;gene_biotype=protein_coding
```

Any idea why it's here, what it's for and how i could avoid it? I fear it might become a problem when using it in third-party softwares.

I imported only the bcbio-gff package, but I believe it's part of Biopython, link: https://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing

Comment: A reproducible example would be nice :) Until then it is hard to know what might be wrong. https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges can also read/write GFFs, dunno if it might solve your problem.

Comment: What I did: extract the info from a GFF file (using GFF.parse() with a limit_info being some genes) , and then send it directly to GFF.write() to create a new file with only the selected genes

Comment: This question might get more answers in the bioinformatics stackexchange site: bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question - "Why it is there?"

- I only presume, that by default the package author wanted to export as much information as possible.

To your next question - "How can I avoid it?"

- Unfortunately there is no off switch. For me the solution was to remove any annotations from the exported sequences. (i.e. set the `annotations` attribute to empty dictionary before calling the `GFF.write()`.

Example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from BCBio import GFF

g = SeqIO.read('NC_003888.3.gb','gb')

g.annotations = {}

with open('t2.gff', 'w') as f:
    GFF.write([g], f)
```

Output file head - no `# annotation remark`

```
head t2.gff 
##gff-version 3
##sequence-region NC_003888.3 1 8667507
NC_003888.3 feature source  1   8667507 ... removed for clarity ....
```